# Decrypt SES message from S3 with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, amazon-kms, node-crypto

I am trying to decrypt a KMS encrypted AWS SES message stored in S3.

Everything works fine (getting the object and metadata from s3, decrypting the key with KMS) until I try to decrypt the content with the decrypted Key:

```js
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { KMSClient, DecryptCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-kms';
import { createDecipheriv } from 'crypto';

const s3 = new S3Client( {
    // ...credentials
} );

const kms = new KMSClient( {
    // ...credentials
} );

const getFromS3AndDecrypt = ( Bucket, Key ) => {

    // GetObject command
    const command = new GetObjectCommand( {
        Bucket,
        Key,
    } );
    
    // Get the object from S3
    const { Metadata, Body } = await s3.send( command );

    // Convert to Buffer
    const body = await streamToBuffer( Body );

    // Get KMS Metadata
    var {
        [ 'x-amz-key-v2' ]: kmsKeyBase64,
        [ 'x-amz-iv' ]: iv,
        [ 'x-amz-tag-len' ]: tagLenBits = 0,
        [ 'x-amz-cek-alg' ]: algo,
        [ 'x-amz-matdesc' ]: matdesc,
    } = Metadata;

    // Convert tagLenBits to Bytes
    const tagLen = tagLenBits / 8;

    // Get encryption context
    const encryptionContext = JSON.parse( matdesc );

    // Get algorithm
    switch ( algo ) {

        case 'AES/GCM/NoPadding':
            algo = `aes-256-gcm`;
            break;

        case 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding':
            algo = `aes-256-cbc`;
            break;

        default:
            throw new Error( `Unsupported algorithm ${ algo }` );

    }

    // Convert kmsKey to Buffer
    const kmsKeyBuffer = Buffer.from( kmsKeyBase64, 'base64' );

    // DecryptCommand
    const kmsCommand = new DecryptCommand( {
        CiphertextBlob: kmsKeyBuffer,
        EncryptionContext: encryptionContext,
    } );

    // Decrypt the key with KMS
    const { Plaintext } = await kmsClient.send( kmsCommand );

    // Create decipher with key and iv
    const decipher = createDecipheriv( algo, Buffer.from( Plaintext ), Buffer.from( iv ), {
        authTagLength: 16,
    } );

    // Body without authTag
    const data = body.slice( 0, - tagLen );

    if  ( tagLen !== 0 ) {
        
        // authTag
        const tag = body.slice( - tagLen );

        // Set authTag
        decipher.setAuthTag( tag );

    }

    // Decrypt data
    var decrypted = decipher.update( data, 'binary', 'utf8' );
    
    decrypted += decipher.final( 'utf8' );

    return decrypted;

};

// Turn @aws-sdk/client-s3 stream response into buffer @see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-755387549
const streamToBuffer = ( stream ) => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        
    const chunks = [];
    
    stream.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => chunks.push( chunk ) );
    
    stream.on( 'error', reject );
    
    stream.on( 'end', () => resolve( Buffer.concat( chunks ) ) );
    
} );
```

When calling `decipher.final` I get a `Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data` error.

This seems to be either because the `authTag` used doesn't match the one which was used when encrypting the data or because the input and output encoding doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `iv` and Plaintext `key` are already `base64` encoded and thus the encoding needs to be passed to the `Buffer`:

```js
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { KMSClient, DecryptCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-kms';
import { createDecipheriv } from 'crypto';

const s3 = new S3Client( {
    // ...credentials
} );

const kms = new KMSClient( {
    // ...credentials
} );

const getFromS3AndDecrypt = ( Bucket, Key ) => {

    const { Metadata, Body } = await s3.send( new GetObjectCommand( {
        Bucket,
        Key,
    } ) );

    const body = await streamToString( Body );

    const { Plaintext } = await kms.send( new DecryptCommand( {
        CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from( Metadata[ 'x-amz-key-v2' ], 'base64' ),
        EncryptionContext: JSON.parse( Metadata[ 'x-amz-matdesc' ] ),
    } ) );

    const key = Buffer.from( Plaintext, 'base64' );

    const iv = Buffer.from( Metadata[ 'x-amz-iv' ], 'base64' );

    const tag = body.slice( -16 );

    const data = body.slice( 0, -16 );

    const decipher = createDecipheriv( 'aes-256-gcm', key, iv );

    decipher.setAuthTag( tag );

    var decrypted = decipher.update( data, 'binary', 'utf8' );

    decrypted += decipher.final( 'utf8' );

    return decrypted;

};

// Turn @aws-sdk/client-s3 stream response into buffer @see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1877#issuecomment-755387549
const streamToString = ( stream ) => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        
    const chunks = [];
    
    stream.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => chunks.push( chunk ) );
    
    stream.on( 'error', reject );
    
    stream.on( 'end', () => resolve( Buffer.concat( chunks ) ) );
    
} );
```